# How to have startup guide of android app?(e.g. what button to click,.. and etc.)

Tags: android-studio

i don't know whats the name of it but i can give some sample
e.g. highlighted the button with guide

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S612g.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Onboarding.
Follow this official guide from android-
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/onboarding